# Maximization problem related to set of common representatives

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We are given set $\{1, \dots n\}$ and requested to construct $A = \{A_1 \dots A_s\}$, where $|A_i|=k$, $|A| = s$, $A_i \subset \{1, \dots n\}$.

We say that $S$ is a minimal set of common representatives of $A$, if $\forall i \in 1\dots k :S\cap A_i \ne \emptyset$ and $|S|$ is minimal possible.

Task is to propose such configuration of $A$, where $\eta(A) = 2$ and $s$ is maximal.
$\eta(A)$ is amount of different $S$ existing for a given $A$.

**Example**
$\{1, \dots 5\}$  , $k = 3$
$A = \{\{1,2,3\}\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\}\}$
Here, $s = |A| = 3$ and $\eta(S) = 2$, since there are 2 sets of representatives: $\{1\},\{2\}$.

**Solution draft**
We fix two elements from $\{1 \dots n\}$. Suppose, they are $1$ and $2$ without loss of generality.
We construct $A$ with respect to the rule :$\forall i \in 1\dots k : 1 \in A_i, 2 \in A_i$.
All other elements filled with all possible distinct ways.
Then, $|S| = 1$ (it's either $1$ or $2$). Hence $\eta(A) = 2$, while $s= \binom {n-2} {k-2}$.
Problem is, I have no idea how to prove maximality.
I'm also not quite sure that mine solution provides maximal $s$.
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case $n \equiv 1 \mod 2$. We define $n = 2m+1$, $k = m+1$.
Then we can define two sets of representatives, $S_1$ and $S_2$, such that:

- $|S_1| = |S_2| = m$
- $\{1 \dots n\} = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup x$
- $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$
- $S_1 \cap x = \emptyset$
- $S_2 \cap x = \emptyset$.

Then we construct $A$ in such a fashion, so it contains all possible combinations of size k, except those which contain all elements for $S_j$ and $x$.  There are only two of them, so $s = \binom n {\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1} - 2$.

For  $n \equiv 0 \mod 2$ same logic applies but without $x$.
Acquired results would be maximal, since the bigger $|S|$ gives the weaker constraint on $A_i$ structure, and for $\eta(S) = 2$ we cannot enlarge $|S|$ any more without breaking constraint of set minimality.

Comment: shouldn't $A$ be of sets of size $k+1$?

Comment: @JorgeFernández Why it should? $k=m+1$ and $m = \lfloor \frac n 2\rfloor$. The closer $k$ to $m$, the bigger the binomial

Comment: Oh I see, I also have one question: wouldn't the set $2,3,4\dots m,m+1,m+2$ be a minimum set of representatives?

Comment: @JorgeFernández yours example set is of size $m+2$. Representativity property holds for it, but not minimality.

Comment: you said minimality was that no vertex can be removed without losing the representativity property.

Comment: @JorgeFernández, Well that was imprecise formulation from my part. Thanks, I've made an edit to the question.

Comment: Ok, with this new definition your solution seems correct. The bound is extremely good.